# choosing resource type during xml file creating in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, android-sdk-tools

When I want to create a XML file in Android SDK installed ECLIPSE for the purpose of SharedPreferences Activity layout... I do not see that dialog box to appear where I can choose from. 
Following are my files.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.preferences_activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


        }
    });
}

}
```

Preferences.java

```
package com.preferences_activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="@string/button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

preferences_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

In the preferences_activity.xml, this is what I get when I create a xml file.

But I wanted to choose a type called preferences while creating a xml file. preferences layout is one of the type of resource available in the dialog box. Others are like: Layout, Values, Menu, AppWidget Provider Searchable, Animation.

If I had a option to choose a preferences layout option while creating a xml file I would be getting the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<PreferencesScreen
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

My Question is again: Where can I get that dialog box from while creating xml file where I can choose the resource type?
I am sorry if this question sounds funny. But I am struggling with it for few days in a row. 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future Visitors:
I was struggling because I was using eclipse app instead of the one that was under adt-bundle. If you use the app under the adt-bundle, that has a logo with {} and light green background than you will have an options to choose a layout or any sorts of resources while creating an xml file. Pls, one more thing to note, I was having hard time to find a wizard for creating a xml file ( I could do it manually with right clicking the project and other and choosing xml file).. but I m talking about the wizard on the menu bar, you should be able to see it if you use this app under adt-bundle instead of regular eclipse. My answer may not be that likable, but sharing for future android beginners.